# Having trouble locating logically error, for loop with recursion

Tags: arrays, numpy, for-loop, if-statement, recursion

My goal is to print numbers from 1 to 9 with no repeats using the logic:
for each number in the array to be printed,

- check all numbers in that row of the array if there is a repeated number
- else re-roll the random number
  perform these tasks recursively until whole row is filled from 1-9 with no repeated number

  ```
    p = np.zeros((1,9), dtype=int)

    def check_row(i):
      num = random.randint(1,9)
      # check num equal any number in its row
      for nine in range(9):
        if num == p[i][nine]:
            check_row(i)  
        else:
            pass    
      return num

   for j in range(9):
     if p[0][j] == 0:
       p[0][j] = check_row(0)

   print(p)
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
p = np.zeros((1,9), dtype=int)

  def check_row(i):
    num = random.randint(1,9)
    # check num equal any number in its row
    for nine in range(9):
      if num == p[i][nine]:
          num = check_row(i)  
      else:
          pass    
    return num

 for j in range(9):
   if p[0][j] == 0:
     p[0][j] = check_row(0)

 print(p)
```